# fgets() does not return NULL on empty string

Tags: c++, c, string, null, fgets

I recently tried to use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()` to read a string for code security reasons. I used a simple function that I found here to check for errors (no input and too long input). The problem is that whenever i press "ENTER" without actually writing anything, `fgets()` doesn't return `NULL` and my program is not able to show the `NO_INPUT` error.

Here's `main.cpp`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "utilities.h"

int main() {
    int rc;
    char str[20];

    rc = getLine("Enter string: ", str, sizeof(str));
    if(rc == NO_INPUT) {
        printf("[ERROR] No input\n\n");
    } else if(rc == TOO_LONG) {
        printf("[ERROR] Input is too long\n\n");
    } else {
        printf("This is your input: \"%s\"\n\n", str);
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Here's `utilities.h`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OK       0
#define NO_INPUT 1
#define TOO_LONG 2

int getLine(const char *msg, char *buff, size_t len) {  
    if(msg != NULL) {
        printf("%s", msg);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    if(fgets(buff, len, stdin) == NULL /*[+]*/ || strcmp(buff, "\n") == 0) {
        //[-] fflush(stdin);
        return NO_INPUT;
    } else if(buff[strlen(buff)-1] != '\n') {
        //[-] fflush(stdin);
        return TOO_LONG;
    } else {
        buff[strlen(buff)-1] = '\0';
        //[-] fflush(stdin);
        return OK;
    }
}
```

And here's the output:

```
Enter string:
This is your input: ""

Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

I solved my problem by replacing the first `if` statement in `utilities.h` with `if(fgets(buff, len, stdin) == NULL || strcmp(buff, "\n") == 0)`. Doing this, my program will check for input errors OR for empty strings and return the `NO_INPUT` flag.

---

Thanks to everybody who commented and @Peter for answering. I added the aforementioned `if` statement in `utilities.h` and removed every `fflush(stdin)` occurrence. The code now looks as above.

Comment: When you just press ENTER, `fgets()` *does* read a string... with just a newline in it.  It may be a blank line, but there's still a line to read.  It would return NULL if the stream were closed or an error occurred, though.

Comment: Well... before I print the string I make sure to replace the '\n' character with a '\0', however if I compare buff[0] with '\0' the output is still the same... Also, I read the manual and it says `If the end-of-file is encountered while attempting to read a character, the eof indicator is set (feof). If this happens before any characters could be read, the pointer returned is a null pointer (and the contents of str remain unchanged).
If a read error occurs, the error indicator (ferror) is set and a null pointer is also returned (but the contents pointed by str may have changed).`

Comment: So, shouldn't I get `NULL` because the '\n' character was encountered before any other character could be read?

Comment: `'\n'` isn't end of file... it's just a newline character... and it *is* read by `fgets()`.  End of file would happen if the input source were closed and there was nothing left to read (not just nothing *right now* or nothing on that line).

Comment: Voting to reopen as the duplicate is clearly wrong.

Comment: @Dmitri I didn't know it... I read somewhere that `\n` is treated like `eof`. Anyway, have you got any ideas on how to fix my problem? Maybe I could compare the input string with the `\n` character to check if it's "empty", what do you think? @hyde What do you mean? I'm new around here : /

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin

Comment: @sgrontflix Wherever you read that `\n` is treated like EOF is wrong, if you really read it anywhere, which doesn't seem likely.

Comment: @EJP http://digilander.libero.it/uzappi/C/librerie/funzioni/fgets.html I read it from here. Let me translate for you: `fgets() reads a line from the stream and puts it in the buffer pointed by s. At most, (size - 1) characters are read, or until it is reached the new-line '\n' character or the EOF.` I guess I shouldn't have trusted this crappy website... Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem that you "fixed" is believing that a end of line should be treated as end of input.

`NULL` is an indication from `fgets()` that it encountered an error or the end of input when reading from the file (or stream).   A blank line is neither an error nor a marker of end of input.   A human (typing on a keyboard) might choose to interpret a newline as end of input, but a computer program does not - after all, there is nothing stopping a user entering more than one line of input.

Practically, `fgets()` reads a line and indicates the end of that line with a `'\n'` character.    Let's say, we have a file containing

```
ABC

DE

FGHIJ
```

(blank lines interspersed in three lines of text, followed by end of the file).

Let's also that `buffer` is an array of five `char`, and that we read that file using consecutive statements of the form `fgets(buffer, 5, file)`.

So what will `fgets(buffer, 5, file)` do on each call.  Well, with 1 representing the first call, 2 representing the second call, etc we will see results of

1. `"ABC\n"` stored into `buffer`;
2. `"\n"` stored into `buffer`;    (first blank line)
3. `"DE\n"` stored into `buffer`;
4. `"\n"` stored into `buffer`;    (second blank line)
5. `"FGHI"` stored into `buffer`;
6. `"J\n"` stored into `buffer`; and
7. `fgets()` returns `NULL`, and nothing is stored into `buffer`.

The first six calls will all return `&buffer[0]` - not `NULL` - since no error is encountered reading from the file.    Even though there are two blank lines in the input.  The last line, which is longer than the buffer (with the `'\n'` counted) is read in two parts.

Incidentally, your code is using `fflush(stdin)`.   Unfortunately, `fflush()` only has defined behaviour on OUTPUT streams or files.   Using it on `stdin` (or any input stream) gives undefined behaviour.     If it is actually discarding input (which it does with some implementations of the C standard library), you are getting lucky - there are real-world compilers where the resultant behaviour does not discard input.

Comment: `fgets(buffer, 4, file)` will read (up to) *three* characters from the stream into `buffer`, and then add a null character... not *four* (so the first read would be "ABC" without the newline... the next read, still before the blank line, being "\n").

Comment: @Dimitri - correct, thanks for that  ... edited and fixed.   Changed the buffer length, and adjusted accordingly (I didn't want multiple cases of a split line).

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying. I have removed fflush(stdin) as suggested.